# How can i kill all processes in clients that run a program(by shortcut) at server

Tags: c#, kill-process

I have a program on a server(for example `\\192.168.0.1\sharefolder\test.exe`). I put the shortcut of program into clients. Users can run the program by that shortcut. When I want to update my program in server, it occurs an error says "file in use".. now, how can I kill all processes in clients that run my program (by shortcut) on server.
I use this code:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("quartus_pgm"))
{
         process.kill();
}
//file.delete();
```

But this code is not enough because this code only kill processes running on the server and still I can not update the program and the error occurs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahyar, hello!

I recomend you to use "Shadow Copying Assemblies" mechanism provided by .NET. In few words:
1. you have 1 app (exe) that referenced on several dlls (libraries with all logic/UI/...).
2. you can replace dlls without stopping app (exe).

For more information you can read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx).

This approach may require to do some refactoring of your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.